# Websphere: setting Connection pool timeout ignored

Tags: java, connection, timeout, websphere

My EJB  Application lately started frequently throwing

```
com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException
 at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1521)
```

Error Message states for example `"Connection not available, Timed out waiting for 2008"`

Strange fact, the wait time differs from 2001 to about 24000 ms but never reaching 180000 ms.
(Connection pool settings: connection timeout is set to 180s).

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a connection timeout at all. It is a connection *pool* timeout.

Comment: Since the user is confused, you might extend your answer to explain the difference (i.e., the connection pool timeout is used when the pool is empty, the maximum number of connections has been created, and the current thread is waiting for another thread to return a connection to the pool).

Comment: No confusion, just being not precise - sorry for that! Question remains: why isn't the current thread waiting until connection timeout as configured in the connection pool settings? Thread should wait 180s for a connection to become available, but

Comment: Configuration is: Data sources > DB2 Universal JDBC Driver XA DataSource > Connection pools:
  Connection timeout:  180 seconds
  Reap/unused/aged: 180/1800/0 seconds
  
The thread should wait 180 seconds for a connection to become available, but throws ConnectionWaitTimeout exception after just 2 to 24 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Application Server, a ConnectionWaitTimeoutException is thrown when the connection pool is at its maximum size, all of the connections are in use by the application, and the application requests more connections.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21225611.